# Query Mongo for documents with given subfield values (and only this values)

Tags: mongodb-query

A Mongo collection has the following documents:

```
{
  name: containerA,
  tasks: [
    {name: taskA1, foo: bar, status: active}
    {name: taskA2, foo: bar, status: ready}
}
{
  name: containerB,
  tasks: [
    {name: taskB1, foo: bar, status: active}
    {name: taskB2, foo: bar, status: done}
    {name: taskB3, foo: bar, status: failure}
}
{
  name: containerC,
  tasks: [
    {name: taskC1, foo: bar, status: failure}
    {name: taskC2, foo: bar, status: done}
    {name: taskC3, foo: bar, status: done}
}
```

I need a query that returns only the finished container *containerC* with *foo=bar*. "Finished" means *status=done* or *status=failure*.

The query

```
db.container.find({
  tasks: {
    $elemMatch: {
      foo: "bar",
      status: {$in: ["done", "failure"]}
    }
  }
})
```

returns also *containerB* :(

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Specify another matcher for `status` to exclude the values you don't want

```
db.container.find({
  tasks: {
    $elemMatch: {
      foo: "bar",
      status: {
         $in: ["done", "failure"],
         $nin: ["active", "ready"]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: @maxim-pavlov and geoffroy  - Thank you, but it doesn't work: _containerB_ is returned because _taskB2_ and _taskB3_ match the conditions.

Comment: No :( I think because _taskB2_ and _taskB3_ match the _$in_ and _$nin_ condition.

Answer (score 0):

`db.container.find({'tasks.status':{$nin:['active', 'ready']}}, {_id:0, name:1})`